# Perspective bar not displayed in 3.x to 4.x migrated RCP application

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I am migrating eclipse 3.x application to eclipse 4.x using compat layer. after migration I am not able to see the perspective bar in the application even i have added the code

```
configurer.setShowPerspectiveBar(true);
```

Is there any way to display perspective bar in eclipse 4.4.1 RCP application(running on compat layer)?

Comment: Have you tried to run your application with -clearPersistedState flag?

Comment: I tried it, but then i used customized perspective bar code for eclipse 4 as there was some issues with default perspective bar in case of compat layer.

Answer (score 0):

It should be: configurer.setShowPerspectiveBar(true);

Comment: Sorry, It was typo mistake, i am setting it as true but in eclipse 4 perspective bar is not displaying using this code